# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892 - Error on Node.js npm version check

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-start

Node.js - I'm getting the following error on the npm version check:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err
```

```sh
# below error occurs
npm -v
```

[image]

```sh
# below error occurs
npm -v readline-sync
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for many ways to figure out and solve this problem and finally I tried deleting the path *nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin* in Environment variables and it worked fine. Now, `npm -v`, `npm init` and all are working without the above error!